# How to create multiplayer in the game?

Tags: server, unreal-engine4, steam

I'm creating a multiplayer FPS game on Unreal Engine 4.

And don't know one thing - if it is multiplayer so it have to have more than one player. If I want to do this should I rent a server? From which hosting?

I want to release my game on Steam - what should I do to create servers for player? I really don't know and need a steps list.

It won't be a game with a big players count, so I don't need a big and strong server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start there is 2 ways of doing multiplayer.

You can either do it with dedicated servers (server will calculates all actions and send them back to each clients connected to it) or you can make a specific client a "host".

Wich ever you chose depends on the type of game you want to create, an open world type of game like a survival wich needs to be up 24/7 with players going on and off from it would require a dedicated server. On the other hand a coop game or a game wich can stop when player wants with 2 or 3 players could run on a client acting as an host.

If you choose to go for dedicated servers you can work inside unreal engine and tick the "run dedicated server" in the launch menu. As for releasing it and setting up multiple dedicated servers that's out of my knowledge